# Как найти все наиболее часто дублирующиеся элементы с одинаковым количеством в списке python?

Tags: python, list

Допуcтим, что есть список `names = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2]`
здесь есть одинаковые элементы 1 и 2,  выбор падает только на них ибо их количество наиболее встречаемое, ну и их количество одинаково, как это можно сделать?..

Comment: Находите любой самый "популярный" элемент, запоминаете его количество как `n`, получаете все элементы, которых `n` в списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея проста. Сортируем список и считаем повторения пробегая по нему, сравнивая текущий элемент со следующим. Если они !=, то либо добавляем в словарь ответов (если кол-во повторений элемента такое же), либо переопределяем словарь с новым значением (если >).

```
names = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 2]

names.sort()

count = 1
answers = {names[0]: 1}  # ответ формата {значение: число упоминаний}
for i in range(len(names)-1):
    if names[i+1] == names[i]:
        count += 1
    elif count ==  max(answers.values()):
        answers[names[i]] = count
        count = 1
    elif count > max(answers.values()):
        answers = {names[i]: count}
        count = 1

print(answers)
```

Хотелось бы что-нибудь элагантнее, чем max(answers.values()) для доступа к элементу словаря, есть идеи?

Answer (score 3):

можно сделать так:

```
names = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2]

# подсчитать максимальное кол-во элементов
max_count = names.count(max(names, key=lambda i: names.count(i)))

# найти все элементы 
res = {i for i in names if names.count(i) == max_count}

print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

names = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2]

d = Counter(names)                        # Counter({1: 3, 2: 3, 4: 1, 5: 1, 3: 1})
max_occurrences = d.most_common(1)[0][1]  # 3

# [1, 2]
r = [v for v, _ in takewhile(lambda x: x[1] == max_occurrences, d.most_common())]
```